# How to remove underline from the link which has number but keep underline on normal link which has alphabets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please tell me How to remove underline from the link which has number but keep underline on normal link which has alphabets?

I created a demo here but not sure how to do this

```css
a{
  text-decoration:underline;
}

/* 
TODO - Write code either with CSS or JS for the anchors which has text as number to NOT to have underline
*/
```

```html
<a href="#">Login</a>
<a href="#">1111</a>
<a href="#">2222</a>
<a href="#">aavv1111</a>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/developerrky/L9j61q35/4/ demo here but need pending code

Comment: Please always include all relevant code within the question itself. People shouldn't have to go off-site in order to understand what you're asking. I've edited the question for you in this case.

Answer (score 2):

CSS does not have the capability to determine if the content of an element is numeric or not, so you will need to use JS.

You can attempt to parse the text content of each element to an integer. If it works, remove the underline otherwise, keep it. Try this:

```js
$('a').css('text-decoration', function(){
  return isNaN(parseInt($(this).text(), 10)) ? 'underline' : 'none';
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Login</a>
<a href="#">1111</a>
<a href="#">2222</a>
<a href="#">aavv1111</a>
```

Comment: 1) jQuery is tagged in the question. 2) That would be underlined as the OP clearly states: `...which has text as number to NOT to have underline`

Answer (score 0):

You could add another class on the links you don't want to have underlined if your content isn't dynamic or updated.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a.nounderline {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Login</a>
<a href="#" class="nounderline">1111</a>
<a href="#" class="nounderline">2222</a>
<a href="#">aavv1111</a>
```

Comment: I would assume the OP cannot edit the HTML and is asking how to do this programmatically

Comment: Cool but I already know this solution, suppose you have 100 such anchors having numbers and 50 anchors as non number then adding this class to each is not a good idea and tiime taking as well, any way using jquery or css (not) property?

Comment: Fair enough @RAJESHKUMARYADAV. See Rory McCrossan's answer, I think it'll be quite good for you.

Comment: @RAJESHKUMARYADAV if you can amend the HTML, then you absolutely should be doing it that way. Using JS to change the values at runtime is a last resort.